# strange characters at the end of directory in android

Tags: android, linux, file-management

I have an issue with directory creation in Android. I use this code to create a directory if doesn't exist and then create a file under it.

```
dir=new File(Constants.TASK_DIRECTORY);
if(!dir.exists())
dir.mkdirs();
file=new File(dir, FILENAME);   
file.createNewFile();
```

Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes when I check the folder from adb shell I see directories ending with 3 or more `"|"` characters. My directory name format is 
`"Abc_123-10.10.2000 "`. What I see sometimes is exactly the same, but sometimes `"Abc_123-10.10.2000|||"` . I need to access the files under directories with the help of their name format but this situation makes it hard, any help would be appreciated.

I set TASK directory in this code

```
Constants.TASK_DIRECTORY=getFilesDir()+"/"+app.getUserName()+"-"+dt;
```

app is my application object

Edit: Solved this problem, it was because TASK_DIRECTORY was not properly set and contains "|" characters. But how can this be possible?

Comment: What are TASK_DIRECTORY and FILENAME defined as?

Comment: TASK_DIRECTORY is a name like I wrote in question "Abc_123-10.10.2000" it's dynamic, FILENAME is like "12345.xml"

Comment: But is TASK_DIRECTORY a pre-processor definition or a buffer?

Comment: it's directory name created under files directory, I define it myself

Comment: What I'm asking is can you also add the code which shows where you define TASK_DIRECTORY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File can't store or save with  some special character as below.

```
      /\:?*"<>|
```

Comment: Yes that was strange for me too. I can't create directories containing |using mkdir but it happened